# Problem creating an in memory db with hibernate and dbunit maven plugins

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hsqldb, dbunit

I am trying to create create and populate in memory a hsql db schema using hibernate3-maven-plugin and dbunit-maven-plugin maven plugins.

I managed to do it to a file, but no to memory. the hibernate plugin does its work without complaining, but once hibernate plugin is finished, dbunit complains about the db schema, it looks as it is not there any more. As I said, I had this working perfectly with a hsql db in a file, but did not manage to do it in memory.

This is the hibernate plugin code:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>    
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>    
    <version>2.2</version>               
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>hsqlDB</id>
                  <phase>test-compile</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                  </goals>
                     <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                                <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
                            </component>
                        </components>       

                        <componentProperties>
                            <jdk5>true</jdk5>                               
                            <propertyfile>target/test-classes/hibernateconf.properties</propertyfile>
                            <configurationfile>target/test-classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                            <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                        </componentProperties>                                              
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>                    
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>          
                </dependency>                    
             </dependencies>                
        </plugin>
```

hibernateconf.properties contains:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mytestdb;hsqldb.write_delay=false;shutdown=true
hibernate.connection.username=sa
hibernate.connection.password=
hibernate.connection.pool_size=1
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

And this is the dbunit

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
            <configuration>
                <dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.hsqldb.HsqldbDataTypeFactory</dataTypeFactoryName>
                <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
                <username>sa</username>
                <password></password>
                <url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mytestdb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false</url>
                <src>src/test/resources/sample-data.xml</src>
                <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type>

                <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                <transaction>true</transaction>
                <skipOracleRecycleBinTables>true</skipOracleRecycleBinTables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>operation</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>          
                </dependency> 
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And this is the error message:

```
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: ExamplePersonEntity
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:281)
```

¿Does any one have any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The URL indicates the database should be shutdown when the last connection is closed. This works for file databases (although it may not be necessary) but will close and discard a memory database. Change the URL as follows:

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mytestdb;shutdown=false
```

and this one

```
<url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mytestdb;shutdown=false</url>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but that didn't work for me.Originally I had the those db urls, but as I was getting no results, I started playing around with the shutdown parameter and the hsqldb.write_delay one.
Thanks in any case :)

Comment: If it definitely did not work with shutdown=false, then you are using different Java processes for hibernate and dbunit. In this type of setup you need to use an HSQLDB server with a memory database.

Answer (score 0):

I was also researching a related problem. It appears that the in-memory schema does not persist across sessions: http://vageeshhoskere.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/unit-test-with-junit-for-hibernate-using-hsqldb-in-memory/

So, either you can do what needs to be done in a single session (which is rather limiting), or attempt the file version of hsqldb